# Alternative to SetLength

Tags: delphi, dynamic

I'm having a problem with the `SetLength` command.

It's basically this problem:

I work with `WindowsAPI` only as good as I can. My goal is to set a certain size to a dynamic array of chars:

Here is some code to understand:

```
var
thefile : array of char;
// or thefile : array [0..9999] of char; // <---- not really a good way, works tho

FileHandle := CreateFileA(paramstr0, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
dwSize := GetFileSize(FileHandle,NIL);
SetFilePointer(FileHandle, 0, nil, FILE_BEGIN);
SetLength(TheFile, dwsize); // <--- I can't use this
ReadFile(FileHandle, thefile[1], dwSize , dwRead, nil);
CloseHandle (FileHandle);
CloseHandle(CreateFileA (sfile, 0, 0,NIL, CREATE_NEW, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0));
FileHandle := CreateFileA(sFile, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nil, CREATE_ALWAYS, 0, 0);
WriteFile (FileHandle, thefile, dwSize, testCardinal, NIL);
CloseHandle (FileHandle);
```

How can I replace `SetLength`? I would like also to understand how Windows/Delphi allocates the array in memory etc. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have several flaws in your code

1. When you uses the [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function you must check the returned handle against the INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE.
2. Always you  must use try ..  finally to free the resources.
3. You are trying to use the [ReadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function reading the contents inside of the  `thefile` buffer using a index 1, this is wrong you must use a index 0 because the dynamic arrays are zero index based.
4. you are using this code

> CloseHandle(CreateFileA (sfile, 0, 0,NIL, CREATE_NEW,
>   FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,0));

To create an empty file and then using again the CreateFile function to open and write the file, you can do the same in one step

```
  FileHandle := CreateFileA(sFile, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nil, CREATE_NEW, 0, 0);
```

Try this improved version of your code.

Btw, there is nothing wrong with use SetLengh, the problem is explained in the point 3.

```
var
  thefile : array of AnsiChar;
begin

  FileHandle := CreateFileA(paramstr0, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
  if FileHandle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
  try
    dwSize := GetFileSize(FileHandle, nil);
    SetFilePointer(FileHandle, 0, nil, FILE_BEGIN);
    SetLength(TheFile, dwsize);
    ReadFile(FileHandle, thefile[0], dwSize , dwRead, nil);
  finally
    CloseHandle (FileHandle);
  end;

  FileHandle := CreateFileA(sFile, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE, nil, CREATE_NEW, 0, 0);
  if FileHandle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
  try
    WriteFile (FileHandle, thefile[0], dwSize, testCardinal, nil);
  finally
    CloseHandle (FileHandle);
  end;

  SetLength(TheFile, 0);    
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Try and finally is a good tip to prevent errors.

Comment: try..finally does make sense when exceptions are raised but here, I suspect only a short of memory may raise an exception, since Windows APIs does not raise exceptions, but return error codes. For instance, the ReadFile() function may return FALSE on any error. In all cases, using APIs in this case does not make sense. And adding `SetLength(TheFile,0)` at the end is not needed at all - this is already done by the compiler.

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez, you never can be 100% sure where an exception will be raised or if a "inoffensive" line of code can raise an exception, in this case the try...finally ensures close the open file handle. about the error handle maybe i missed mention about use the `RaiseLastOSError` function, finally about the  `SetLength(TheFile,0)` remember which this code is incomplete and we don't know the context, So maybe the `TheFile` variable can be reutilized in another place. Anyway always exist a room to improve an answer, but I think which this one is complete enough.

Comment: @RRUZ I just wanted to state that it would probably better make sense to check for the ReadFile() returned value to ensure all data was read. And that Windows APIs do not raise any exceptions. The code could silently fail, as written.  Whereas `SetLength(TheFile,0)` is truly pointless here - and also calling `SetFilePointer(FileHandle, 0, nil, FILE_BEGIN)`.

Answer (score 4):

`SetLength()` is not the problem here.

If you really like Windows APIs, just use the `CopyFile()` function which will do all the work for you:

```
CopyFile(pointer(paramstr0),pointer(sFile));
```

Using a temporary fixed buffer of several MB will be faster than reading all files at once.

And your code won't be able to handle files > 2GB. You need to handle Int64 size and position in your code.

IMHO you shall better use non Windows APIs here to handle files, but `TFileStream` which is cross platform.

`SetLength()` is perhaps one of the only good calls here - but you should have coded `theFile[0]` or `pointer(theFile)^` instead of `theFile[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GetMem/FreeMem with a generic buffer instead of using a dynamic array. It is much more alike the way you would do it in C.

Anyway setting a buffer as large as the file is not usually the best solution. Usually you use a fixed size buffer and read/write a file in chunks. You may not be able to allocate a whole array, even if there is enough free memory. Array memory needs to be contiguous, thereby you need a free memory block as large as or larger than the array you need to allocate. Memory can get fragmented over time, so a block large enough could not be available.

And even if you're able to allocate it, you may force the OS to swap some memory out of RAM to allocate it - slowing down other applications. The size of the buffer should thereby be set taking into account available RAM, performance, and disks speed.

How Delphi allocates memory depends on what memory manager you're using. Most will request larger blocks using Windows memory allocation functions, and suballocate them as needed (to speed up memory management, Windows was not designed to allocate efficiently small memory blocks as most OO applications do). Blocks can be returned to the OS only when they contains no longer used data.

Why an array of **char**? In Delphi a char is not an 8 bit type. For example it is 8 bit up to Delphi 2007, but a 16 bit type from 2009 onwards, because it became a Unicode char (unlike C). Use the Byte type (or UInt8 in newer versions), it will stay an 8 bit type whatever version of Delphi and target platform you use.

If you need to copy a file, TStream.CopyFrom() will do what you need in a single call (after you've created both streams).

Comment: thank you for your help. I understand more about the memory manager now.